# Call locationRequest when activity opens and then each interval

Tags: android, google-location-services

I have made an app that uses the location of the user.

When the user first creates the account, I had liked it to read his current location and then update it every 60min.

I used the following code:

```
private void initGPS(){
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(60 * 60 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(60 * 60 * 1000);

    new GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn( isGPSEnable -> isGPS = isGPSEnable );

    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                if (location != null) {
                    Lat_Coordinate = location.getLatitude();
                    Lon_Coordinate = location.getLongitude();

                    Map<String, Object> user_location = new HashMap<>();
                    user_location.put( "Lat", Lat_Coordinate );
                    user_location.put( "Lon", Lon_Coordinate );

                    db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "Location" ).document(auth.getUid()).set( user_location );

                    if (!isContinue && mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    if (!isGPS) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{
        isContinue = true;
        getLocation();
    }
}


private void getLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DiscoverActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DiscoverActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DiscoverActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                1000);

    } else {
        if (isContinue) {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
        } else {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(DiscoverActivity.this, location -> {
                if (location != null) {
                    Lat_Coordinate = location.getLatitude();
                    Lon_Coordinate = location.getLongitude();
                } else {
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1000: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (isContinue) {
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                } else {
                    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(DiscoverActivity.this, location -> {
                        if (location != null) {
                            Lat_Coordinate = location.getLatitude();
                            Lon_Coordinate = location.getLongitude();
                        } else {
                            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code does the job of updating the location every 60min however it does not update right when the activity started.

Right now what I'm doing is that in order to avoid bugs later in the code I initialize the location (in order to have a path in firebase) but then when the activity starts, it does not change the initialization that I did.

What I try to say is:

Is there a way to make like "one time" get location when activity opened and then to use the code above that will update every 60min?

Thank you

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: added the things that connected to a location in this activity